# How to deploy devstack (OpenStack) on RHEL 9.1?

Tags: openstack, devstack, rhel9

I want to install DevStack(Yoga) on RHEL 9.1 (https://opendev.org/openstack/DevStack).
I attempted to deploy using the official manual (https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/get-started-openstack-devstack).

However, the deployment got stuck due to the unavailability of the "redhat-lsb-core" package while running the '$./stack.sh' command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the code](https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack/src/branch/master/functions-common#L408), it appears that the `redhat-lsb-core` package is only required by the `GetOSVersion` function, and there are already explicit provisions in place for both CentOS and Rocky 9, both of which, like RHEL9, do not include the redhat-lsb-core package:

```
function GetOSVersion {
    # CentOS Stream 9 does not provide lsb_release
    source /etc/os-release
    if [[ "${ID}${VERSION}" == "centos9" ]]; then
        os_RELEASE=${VERSION_ID}
        os_CODENAME="n/a"
        os_VENDOR=$(echo $NAME | tr -d '[:space:]')
    elif [[ "${ID}${VERSION}" =~ "rocky9" ]]; then
        os_VENDOR="Rocky"
        os_RELEASE=${VERSION_ID}
    else
        _ensure_lsb_release

        os_RELEASE=$(lsb_release -r -s)
        os_CODENAME=$(lsb_release -c -s)
        os_VENDOR=$(lsb_release -i -s)
    fi

    ...
```

It looks like you could probably get things working in RHEL9 by treating it like centos9, perhaps like this:

```
function GetOSVersion {
    # CentOS Stream 9 does not provide lsb_release
    source /etc/os-release
    if [[ "${ID}${VERSION}" == "centos9" ]]; then
        os_RELEASE=${VERSION_ID}
        os_CODENAME="n/a"
        os_VENDOR=$(echo $NAME | tr -d '[:space:]')
    elif [[ "${ID}${VERSION}" == rhel9.* ]]; then
        os_RELEASE=${VERSION_ID}
        os_CODENAME="n/a"
        os_VENDOR=$(echo $NAME | tr -d '[:space:]')
    elif [[ "${ID}${VERSION}" =~ "rocky9" ]]; then
        os_VENDOR="Rocky"
        os_RELEASE=${VERSION_ID}
    else
      ...
```

On a RHEL 9.1 system, this will set:

```
os_RELEASE=9.1
os_CODENAME=n/a
os_VENDOR=RedHatEnterpriseLinux
```

That will hopefully be enough to move things forward.

Comment: I tried modifying the functions-common file with 'rhel9.*' but I am stuck with a new error-   'Support for rhel9 is incomplete: no support for installing packages'

Comment: The project lists as their primary goal, "To quickly build dev OpenStack environments in a clean Ubuntu or Fedora environment". It sounds like support for RHEL9 or derivatives is a "best effort" sort of thing. If you're just starting out the easiest solution might be to use one of their primary targets (Ubuntu or Fedora). I use neither devstack nor RHEL 9, so you've reached the limit of the suggestions I can provide.

Comment: I tried using Ubuntu, but Devstack Yoga requires python 3.9, which I was unable to find. it doesn't appear to be compatible based on comments in https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1997017
However, Ubuntu 20.04 and DevStack Yoga on Python 3.8 works perfectly.

Comment: do you have any suggestions to solve the error- 'Support for rhel9 is incomplete: no support for installing packages'

Comment: I don't have any suggestions other than (a) examine the script and make the necessary changes to resolve the error, or (b) use a supported platform instead of RHEL 9.